# Cannot add foreign key constraint even with the same data type

Tags: mysql

```
| section | CREATE TABLE `section` (
  `CourseNumber` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Quarter` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `RoomNumber` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DayTime` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CourseNumber`,`Quarter`),
  CONSTRAINT `section_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CourseNumber`) REFERENCES `Course` (`CourseNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |


| enrollment | CREATE TABLE `enrollment` (
  `SSN` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CourseNumber` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Quarter` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Grade` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `SSN` (`SSN`),
  KEY `CourseNumber` (`CourseNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `enrollment_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`SSN`) REFERENCES `Student` (`SSN`),
  CONSTRAINT `enrollment_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`CourseNumber`) REFERENCES `Course` (`CourseNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |



mysql> alter table enrollment add foreign key(Quarter) references section(Quarter);
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Column `Quarter` in both table Enrollment and Section have the datatype VARCHAR(10),so I am not sure what is causing the error.

Comment: Maybe there's data violating the new constraint?

Answer (score 0):

If tables have data which do not respect foreign key you can not create it.
Try

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
alter table enrollment add foreign key(Quarter) references section(Quarter);
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

But i have used this to delete tables, do not know what will happen in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a two fold problem...

- Column `Quarter` is not already indexed in the target table `enrollment`.
- Column `Quarter` is also not indexed in the source table `section`, although it is a part of the composite `PRIMARY KEY` along with `CourseNumber`.

So, if you just want `Quarter` from `section` table to be referenced in `enrollment` table, you'd need to:

```
ALTER TABLE `section` ADD INDEX( `Quarter`);
ALTER TABLE `enrollment` ADD INDEX( `Quarter`);
```

And thereafter:

```
ALTER TABLE enrollment ADD FOREIGN KEY(`Quarter`) REFERENCES section(`Quarter`);
```

---

However, if you want `(CourseNumber, Quarter)` as a composite foreign key, you would need to create a combined index on the two fields in `enrollment` table:

```
ALTER TABLE `enrollment` ADD INDEX( `CourseNumber`, `Quarter`);
```

And follow it up with:

```
ALTER TABLE `enrollment` ADD FOREIGN KEY( `CourseNumber`, `Quarter` ) 
                      REFERENCES section( `CourseNumber`, `Quarter` );
```

Comment: My `SSN`, `CourseNumber` do not cause any error, why is `Quarter` causing the problem but not `SSN` and `CourseNumber`?

Comment: Because you have `KEY SSN (SSN)`, which creates an index implicitly

Comment: Note that MySQL will automatically create an index in the referencing table, so you only have to add the index manually to `section`.

Answer (score 0):

Must be some data preventing the creation as others have said. This worked fine when I ran it:

```
CREATE TABLE `Course` (
  `CourseNumber` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CourseNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `Student` (
  `SSN` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SSN`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `section` (
  `CourseNumber` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Quarter` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `RoomNumber` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DayTime` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CourseNumber`,`Quarter`),
  CONSTRAINT `section_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CourseNumber`) REFERENCES `Course` (`CourseNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `enrollment` (
  `SSN` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CourseNumber` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Quarter` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Grade` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `SSN` (`SSN`),
  KEY `CourseNumber` (`CourseNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `enrollment_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`SSN`) REFERENCES `Student` (`SSN`),
  CONSTRAINT `enrollment_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`CourseNumber`) REFERENCES `Course` (`CourseNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```